# Don't understand IndexError from for loop

Tags: python

So I've got this code for a school project (which explains the variable names) but when I get to the for loop at the bottom it says the list index is out of range. It is supposed to input a username and then check it before asking for a password. I've tried to figure out what is wrong but nothing works.

```
def passwordSystem():
    #TASK ONE
    username_array = []
    password_array = []
    for i in range (1, 30):
        username_to_be_entered = str(input("Enter a username"))
        acceptable_password = False
        while not acceptable_password:
            password_to_be_entered = str(input("Enter a password between 6 and 12 characters"))
            if len(password_to_be_entered) > 12 or len(password_to_be_entered) < 6:
                print ("Your password was not between 6 and 12 characters")
            else:
                acceptable_password = True
                print ("Password accepted")
        print ("Your username is:" ,username_to_be_entered)
        print ("Your password is:" ,password_to_be_entered)
    #TASK TWO
    username_accepted = False
    while not username_accepted:
        username_to_be_checked = str(input("Please enter your username"))
        for i in range (1, 30):
            if username_array[i] == username_to_be_checked:
                print ("Username accepted")
                username_accepted = True
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the whole array yourself. You can just use `in`

Comment: Also the username array stays empty forever, so when you try to check `username_array[i]` you'll always be past the end of the array.

Comment: Also, where are you putting usernames into the `username_array` variable?  I only see two instances, line 3, and line 21.  If that's the case, you would get the out of range error because the size of the list `username_array` is 0 right?  So you are trying to grab something at an index from an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Your lists remain empty forever. In this code block you need to append the username and password to their respective lists.

```
while not acceptable_password:
    password_to_be_entered = str(input("Enter a password between 6 and 12 characters"))
    if len(password_to_be_entered) > 12 or len(password_to_be_entered) < 6:
        print ("Your password was not between 6 and 12 characters")
    else:
        acceptable_password = True
        username_array.append(username_to_be_entered)
        password_array.append(password_to_be_entered)
        print ("Password accepted")
```

Then, to check the username, you should just use the `in` keyword instead of manually iterating over the whole list.

```
#TASK TWO
username_accepted = False
while not username_accepted:
    username_to_be_checked = str(input("Please enter your username"))
    if username_to_be_checked in username_array:
        print ("Username accepted")
        username_accepted = True
```